# GLMMadaptive - Hessian matrix problem Hurdle Beta Model

Tags: r, mixed-model, beta-regression, hessian, glmmadaptive

**Data:**

I have a percentage (or proportion see paragraph below) outcome dataset with a high number of zero's. I have therefore attempted to run a hurdle beta model using the GLMMadaptive package in R. I would like to predict this percentage outcome that is measured in two groups of animals: one heterogeneous genotype group (het) and one wildtype group (wt). For each animal, this outcome is measured in 5 subsequent sessions (one day apart), each session contains 42 measurements.

As discussed in the comments below, the outcome (or response variable) is not a continuous percentage, but rather a proportion. As it reflects the number of miss steps out of the total number of steps taken during 1 trial. The number of total steps per trial varies, though these absolute numbers are not known (not in the dataset). So I, therefore, see no option to convert this model to a count model.

The data divided over the genotypes and sessions looks like this:
[image: data]

**Model:**

For the model I would like to test an interaction between genotype and session in the fixed part, both the zero-inflated and the beta part. To account for the multiple measurements per animal within a session, the random part contains random intercepts per animal ID. The code looks like this:

`mixed_model(fixed = perc~Genotype*Session, random =~1|MouseIdentifier, data=data1, family=hurdle.beta.fam(), na.action=na.exclude, zi_fixed=~Genotype*Session, zi_random=~1|MouseIdentifier, n_phis = 1)`

**PROBLEM:**

This model gives me the error concerning the Hessian matrix:

"Hessian matrix at convergence is not positive definite; unstable solution."

If I look at the summary of the model, I see that the fixed effects coefficients are showing a lot NaN values, in contrast to the Zero-part coefficients:

[image: model summary output]

**Solutions attempted:**
I've tried to add `penalized = T` to the model code, as I thought that the NaNs in the fixed part could be a sign of separation, this improved it slightly, as there were more coefficients calculated, though not all. But it still contained some NaNs and thus still gave me the error.

I tried to simplify the model: remove the interaction, remove either predictor (Genotype or Session). Though the error remained.

I also tried to simplify the Session variable. Genotype only has two levels, so can't be meaningfully simplified. I went from 5 sessions, to 2 sessions, with sessions 1,2 and 3 now being session 1 and session 4 and 5 being session 2. This improved it the most, only the intercept in the fixed part gives NaNs now. Though still the SEs of the other coefficients are minuscule and the error remains obviously. Adding the `penalized = T` argument did not further improve this:

[image: simplified model summary outcome]

**QUESTION:**
Is there any other way I could attempt to improve this hessian matrix situation? Is there an error in my code that I'm overlooking? Are there alternative glmms? Any input would be highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What scale is your response variable *perc* expressed on? It seems to me that it should be expressed on the 0 to 1 scale for the beta distribution to make sense? If it is expressed on the 0 to 100 scale, you should convert *perc* (percentage) to *prop* (proportion) and then include *prop* as the response in your model.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment! The response variable is indeed on the 0-1 scale.

Comment: In your variable naming conventions, you should be consistent and have names that reflect the underlying scale of the variable (e.g., don’t use *perc* for a proportion variable; use *prop*). This is especially important if you need to share your code with others.

Comment: In statistics, proportions are categorized as either *discrete* or *continuous*. Discrete proportions are computed as the ratio of two counts (e.g., 4/10 or 0.4 would represent the proportion of successes in 10 trials). Continuous proportions are computed as the ratio of two positive numbers (e.g., 20.5/60.7 or 0.34 would represent a proportion of total area where a certain plant species was spotted). This categorization is important, as it determines the most appropriate model to consider for proportion data.

Comment: From your post, it seems (?) that your proportions are in fact discrete proportions. Can you clarify how those proportions were derived? Also, one of your tags mentions *zero-inflation* but the post itself talks about *hurdle* modelling. Are you sure you need to consider hurdle modelling rather than zero-inflated modelling in your context?

Comment: I indeed think these are proportions. These data are the number of missteps animals take on a specific walking/running course out of the total number of steps. Each trial they go over the course once. The total number of steps varies from trial to trial as you can imagine.

Comment: Considering the hurdle vs. zero-inflated issue, the `hurdle.beta.fam` argument asks you to define a zero-inflated part of the model (at least in the context of the GLMMadaptive package). And from what I understood until now, a hurdle model can be used to analyse continuous data with excess zero's. Also see this GLMMadaptive vignette under "Two-Part Mixed Effects Models for Semi-Continuous Data" (I realize that they don't give a hurdle beta example here): https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/ZeroInflated_and_TwoPart_Models.html.

Comment: Though, as my data are proportions, not percentages, this might not apply anymore? My dataset does not have the original count data on which the proportions are based, unfortunately.